# Does Canon PowerShot G15 have manual F-number adjustment

Tags: canon, exposure, manual-mode, features, specification

As the question says, I have not been able to find out whether Canon PowerShot G15 has a manual F-number adjustment. I went through some reviews and specs but I haven't seen this there.

I'm asking because I'm going to buy a camera, and one of those I consider (Panasonic Lumix DMC-LX7) features this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does. This falls under **full manual-controls on most review sites**.

You can tell this by simply looking at photos of the G15 and noting the positions on the mode-dial. The one labbeled **A** means you can select aperture while leaving the shutter-speed automatic and the **M** means that you can adjust both independently.

The G15 also happens to have dual control-dials, so you can adjust both aperture and shutter-speed easily.